# How to make stringline from points with django geojson

Tags: javascript, python, django, leaflet, geojson

According my django model, i have TravelPoint model with geojson field
But i want to draw a string line from point to point (Travel.Route model)

```
# coding: utf-8

from djgeojson.fields import PointField, LineStringField
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField



class TravelPoint(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    geom = PointField()
    description = RichTextField()

    def __unicode__(self):             
        return unicode(self.name)

    @property
    def popupContent(self):
      return '<h3>{}</h3><p>{}</p>'.format(
          self.name.encode('utf-8').strip(),
          self.description.encode('utf-8').strip())


class TravelRoute(models.Model):
    geom = LineStringField()
```

I will think about define some method wich grab points and put it in geojson line field, but my poor knownleadges stops me.

Another way draw line in javascript, but also diffucult to understand.

In template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var collection = {{ points|geojsonfeature:"popupContent"|safe }};

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
          layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
        }
    }

    function map_init(map, options) {
        L.geoJson(collection, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);



    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you're breaking some Django MVC rule : you have a method/property which returns HTML, you should use django views preferably.

Regarding your JS/Python code, I would do it in 2 steps :

- 1st, implement a view in Django that returns the geojson payload (using HttpResponse and specifying the mimetype or using JsonResponse in Django 1.7)
- 2nd, in JS, use Ajax to get response from previously implemented Django view, then in the js callback function, call L.geoJson